# Minimizing $\tan^2 x+\frac{\tan^2 y}{4}+\frac{\tan^2 z}{9}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization

> Given that $\tan x+2\tan y+3\tan z=40 , \ \ \ x,y,z \in \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{3\pi}{2}\right),$
>
> We need to find the minimum value of $ \tan^2 x+\dfrac{\tan^2 y}{4}+\dfrac{\tan^2 z}{9}$

One way would be to consider the vectors 
$$\begin{align}
&\vec{v_1}=\tan x \ \hat{i}+\dfrac{\tan y}{2} \ \hat{j}+\dfrac{\tan z}{3} \ \hat{k} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and}\\ &\vec{v_2}=\hat{i}+4 \ \hat{j}+9 \ \hat{k}
\end{align}$$

And then apply to them the inequality $\left(\vec{v_1} \cdot \vec{v_2}\right)^2 \leq \left|\vec{v_1}\right|^2 \left|\vec{v_2}\right|^2$.

Using this we get $\tan^2 x+\dfrac{\tan^2 y}{4}+\dfrac{\tan^2 z}{9} \geq \dfrac{1600}{98}$

Is this method fine?

What are other methods to solve this problem, which do not involve vectors or complex numbers? Can this result be obtained by using elementary calculus?

Thank you.

Comment: Use lagrange multipliers... you have a function to maximize/minimize, and a restriction.

Comment: can you tell where you got the question, the topic or context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $\tan$ are allowed to span the whole real range, so we can define
$$X=\tan x,Y=\frac12\tan y,Z=\frac13\tan z.$$
The planar constraint becomes
$$X+4Y+9Z=40,$$
and we must find the point closest to the origin (minimize $X^2+Y^2+Z^2$).

This point is obviously on the normal to the plane through the origin, let $(X,Y,Z)=\frac d{\sqrt{98}}(1,4,9)$. Plugging into the plane equation, we have
$$\frac d{\sqrt{98}}(1\cdot1+4\cdot4+9\cdot9)=40,$$
and the requested squared distance is $$d^2=\frac{1600}{98}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Define $f:\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}\right)^3\to \Bbb R$ putting $$f(x,y,z) =  \tan^2 x+\dfrac{\tan^2 y}{4}+\dfrac{\tan^2 z}{9} $$
You want to optimize $f$ subject to $$g(x,y,z) = \tan x+2\tan y+3\tan z=40$$

Call $u = \tan x$, $v = \tan y$ and $w = \tan z$. Since $x,y,z \in \left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$, we have that $u,v,w \in \Bbb R$.

It seems easier to me work with: $$\tilde{f}(u,v,w) = u^2 + \frac{v^2}{4} + \frac{w^2}{9}$$ and the restriction: $$\tilde{g}(u,v,w) = u + 2v + 3w = 40$$

Now use Lagrange Multipliers and solve: $$\begin{cases} \nabla \tilde{f}(u,v,w) = \lambda \nabla \tilde{g}(u,v,w) \\ \tilde{g}(u,v,w) = 40 \end{cases}.$$

Your method seems fine to me, though.

Comment: Well..I don't know what Lagrange Multipliers are, I am frankly just a high school student

Comment: This may not be helpful to Pkwssis, but I bet it will be to someone starting in [CoV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) (+1)

Comment: Thanks. OP asked for a method using "elementary calculus", I thought that this would do. I think I misjudged it :(

Answer (score 3):

Your method is equivalent to the following
$$
a+2b+3c=40
$$
$$
\text{minimize }a^2+\frac14b^2+\frac19c^2
$$
Cauchy-Schwarz says that
$$
1\cdot a+4\cdot\frac12b+9\cdot\frac13c\le\sqrt{1+4^2+9^2}\sqrt{a^2+\frac14b^2+\frac19c^2}
$$
where equality occurs only when $\left.\left(a,\frac12b,\frac13c\right)\middle\|\left(1,4,9\right)\right.$.

That is,
$$
1600\le98\left(a^2+\frac14b^2+\frac19c^2\right)
$$
and that for some $(a,b,c)$, like $\left(\frac{40}{98},\frac{320}{98},\frac{1080}{98}\right)$, equality holds.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$a:=\tan x,b:=\frac12 \tan y,c:=\frac13\tan z$$
Now $a+4b+9c=40$ and we need to minimize $(a^2+b^2+c^2)$

Now using Cauchy Schwarz: $$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(1+16+81)\ge(a+4b+9c)^2$$